# access variable in a array in class

Tags: php, class

How I solve this problem. I want to access a variable in an array

```
class testClass{
   public $variable;
   public function __construct(){
       $this->variable = 3; //assign value to variable
   }

   public $arr = array(
       'index' => $this->variable//here show the error
   )
}
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot initialize a class property like that. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

So you need to put this in the constructor:

```
public $arr = array(
   'index' => $this->variable//here show the error
)
```

as something like:

```
public function __construct(){
   $this->variable = 3; //assign value to variable

   // here you can assign your variable using another property
   $this->arr = array(
      'index' => $this->variable//here show the error
   );
}
```

Comment: Seems like the day of these questions; We already had a similar one today: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29538287/3933332 :) (Also if OP doesn't define the property `$arr`in the definition it will automatically be public)

Comment: @Rizier123 To be honest, it's bound to be a duplicate but I couldn't find one fast enough, writing an answer was easier. And the subject must be on the curriculum today ;-)

Comment: It's all about knowing if there is a dupe or not. But this Q has a few other aspects in it. Like what visibility a property has if it is defined in the constructor.

Comment: @Rizier123 The OP is actually defining it. After the constructor but still. And as public as well so I don't think that that's a real issue here. It's actually exactly the same as the question you linked to in the other question with the difference that there is a constructor between the property definitions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't do that in a `default` value;

You have 2 options;
One, setting it via the construct:

```
class testClass{
    public $variable;
    public $arr;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->variable = 3;
        $this->arr = array('index' => $this->variable);
    }
}
```

Two,  using a function;

```
class testClass{
    public $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->variable = 3;
    }

    public function arr()
    {
        return array(
            'index' => $this->variable,
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class testClass
{
   protected $arr = array();
   protected $variable; // define this class variable only if you use it in another method

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->variable = 3;
       $this->setArrElements(array('index' => $this->variable));
   }

   public function doSomething()
   {
       echo $this->arr['index'];
   }

   public function getArr()
   {
       return $this->arr;
   }

   public function addArrElements(Array $elements)
   {
       $this->arr = array_merge($this->arr, $elements);
   }
}

$test = new testClass();
$test->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a getter and setter method.

```
class testClass{
   public $variable;
   public $arr;

   public function __construct(){
       $this->variable = 3; //assign value to variable
       $this->arr = array('index' => $this->variable);
   }

   public function getArr($key) {
      return $this->arr[$key];
   }

   public function setArr($key, $val) {
      return $this->arr[$key] = $val;
   }
}

$testClass = new testClass();

print $testClass->getArr('index');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class testClass{
   public $variable;
   public $arr = array();

   public function __construct(){
      $this->variable = 3; //assign value to variable
      $this->arr["index"] = $this->variable;
   }

}

$test = new testClass();
echo $test->arr["index"]; // shows the value off index;
```

This is the right way to add and access values in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

To give a different perspective/answer. You can/should use constants to define your default values so they can be easily referenced/overridden when extending the object., instead of needing to override every object/variable that implements that value.

```
class testClass
{

    const DEFAULT_INDEX = 3;

    public $variable = self::DEFAULT_INDEX;

    public $arr = array(
       'index' => self::DEFAULT_INDEX
    );
}
```

http://ideone.com/o5EavE

If you are wanting to always reference `$this->variable` as the `testClass::$arr['index']`, I suggest the use of a setter/getter as was also provided below.